# Trying to figure it out

Tags: html, css

I want all the answers to my statements to start at the same place. Like for instance favorite tv show and twitter answer all to start at the same place with the even amount of spacing in between. I have the code listed below. I also added a photo of what it looks like. I know it's simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out

```css
html {

 min-height: 100%:;
 overflow: hidden;
}

body {

 height: calc( 100vh - 8em);
 padding: 4em;
 background-color: black;
 text-align: left;
}

p {
 font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: white;

}

h4 {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
 color: #89e20b;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
 color: #89e20b;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
 color: #89e20b;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
 color: #89e20b;
}

h5 {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
 color: #89e20b;
}
 .line {

  position: left;
  top: 35%;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
 }

 img {

  align-content: left;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Web Developer</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
 <img src="jcblogo.png" height="45" width="160">
 <div>
 <p><h4> # General Information</h4></p>
  
  <p><h4>#-------------------------------</h4></p>
 </div>
  
  <p>name    :Jacob Olenick</p>
  <p>Occupation    :Designer and Developer</p>
  <p>Location    :Las Vegas</p>
  
  <div>
  <p><h3># Past Work</h3></p>
   
   <p><h3>#-------------------------------</h3></p>
  </div>
   
   <p>Creative    @ Vous Church</p>
   <p>Creative    @ King's Church</p>
   <p>Creative    @ Relentless Church</p>
   <p>Creative    @ Hillsong Las Vegas</p>
   <p>Developer   @ Chrishan Technology Solutions</p>
   <p>Creative Director    @ Givary 
    
    <div>
    <p><h2># About Me</h2></p>
    
    <p><h2>#-------------------------------<h2></p>
    <div>
    
    <p>Husband to    : Megan Olenick</p>
    <p>Favorite Drink    : Coffee/Orange Juice</p>
    <p>Favorite City    : NYC
    <p>Favorite Preacher    : Carl Lentz</p>
    <p>Best TV Show    : Stranger Things/Chicago PD
    
    
    <div>
    <p><h1># Social and Contact</h1></p>
    
    <p><h1>#-------------------------------</h1></p>
   </div>
    
    <p>twitter    @jacobolenick</p>
    <p>instagram    @jacobolenick</p>
    <p>behance    /jacobolenick</p>
    <p>github    /jacobolenick</p>
    <p>email    olenickjacob@gmail.com</p>
    
    <p><h5>Love what you do and honor God</h5></p>



</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!, can you show what you have tried so far ? What issue are you facing ?

Comment: I just have them wrapped in <p> tags

Comment: you may improve your question by providing a [mcve]. For further informations about this site please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: This is where you use a table.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use a `table`:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>: Jacob Olenick</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Occupation</td>
    <td>: Designer and Developer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>: Las Vegas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways, but some basic css as pointer

```css
.question {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.answer::before {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <span class="question">
                Name
            </span>
    <span class="answer">
                Jacob O
            </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="question">
                Occupation
            </span>
    <span class="answer">
                Designer and Dev
            </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This answere is not responsive or generic because it is tied to the `width: 150px` in the css.